# Get intermediate output from Keras/Tensorflow during prediction and modify the value before passing to next layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to modify the values of each layers during prediction process. I have one convolution layer, dense layer and output layer (softmax).

I want to modify the result of convolution layer's output  before passing it to hidden layers during prediction time.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K
from keras.utils import to_categorical
# make a prediction for a new image.
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd# load and prepare the image
def load_image(img):#
    # load the image
    #img = load_img(filename, grayscale=True, target_size=(28, 28))
    # convert to array
    #img = img_to_array(img)
    # reshape into a single sample with 1 channel
    img = img.reshape(1, 28, 28, 1)
    # prepare pixel data
    img = img.astype('uint8')
    img = img #/ 255
    return img
data_test = pd.read_csv('mnistdata/mnist_testE.csv')
X_test = np.array(data_test.iloc[:, 1:])
y_test = to_categorical(np.array(data_test.iloc[:, 0]))
# load an image and predict the class
#X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)#def run_example():
    # load the image
img = load_image(X_test[1])
    # load model
model = load_model('final_modelv4.h5')
digit = model.predict_classes(img)
print(digit)
```

Can anyone guide me how to modify this code to change the values of each layer's results?

Comment: during prediction time? one question, WHY?

Comment: i wan to  downsample the values of each activation layers so that i can model it on chip in just 8bits

Comment: you can use [TF Lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite) instead of manually doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Providing the solution here (Answer Section), even though it is present in the Comments Section, for the benefit of the community.

You can Convert a TensorFlow model into a compressed flat buffer with the TensorFlow Lite Converter. Quantize by converting 32-bit floats to more efficient 8-bit integers or run on GPU.

You can find details about tensroflow lite [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite).

This page will be most relevant for your query - [Get started with TensorFlow Lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/get_started#4_optimize_your_model_optional)